# Solving the Error " TypeError at /editprofile/ context must be a dict rather than set."

Tags: python, django

I got some troubles with solving of "TypeError at /editprofile/
context must be a dict rather than set." in my Django project. I'm trying to allow the users to edit their personal information but I keep getting an error. I tried to read everything here and in other pages but nothing has helped, I would love to know how to solve this if anyone could direct me or give me some tips on how to fix this.

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'country'
        )
```

views.py

```
def editprofile(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render(request, 'movies_app/profile.html')
        else:
            form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
            args = {'form', form}
            return render(request, 'movies_app/editprofile.html', args)
```

editprofile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
    <title>Edit form</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The issue is at here. `args = {'form', form}`. The `args` must be a dictionary object not set

Comment: It should be `{'form': form}` instead of `{'form', form}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `views.py` `args` should be a `dict`, you should replace the `,` for a `:`.

Comment: woow i never realized {a, b} was a shorthand for sets definition! amazing!